# IIS Method to display HTML depending on type of server

Tags: iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I've just set up IIS 8.5 on our new development server. Due to lack of resources we have our staging and testing environments on this machine in two separate IIS sites.

It would be nice to have some sort of site-wide HTML that would remind the developers which site they're connected to. A small banner along the top of all hosted web apps with "Staging environment" or "Testing environment" would be useful, but I'm not sure how you'd enforce this over all sites and their web apps.

Is this even possible? I'm asking about methods that wouldn't require a change to the code base of the web apps themselves.

Comment: you would want to overwrite the basic http get handler/module, never attempted this.  usually just use this on the code side using the web.config to know where i am, up voting as im interested

Comment: take a look at this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

just hard code "Staging environment" or "Testing environment" in the module

the html is up to you

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I managed to get it working eventually and I'll return with a good write up once I have the time.

Comment: did you got with overrride of the http module or using the web.config